# Is it possible to submit values of a form to two pages from a button based on button name?

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I have one form which goes to another page and does some database operations.

```
 <form id="form1" method="post" action="goes_to_page1.php" onsubmit="return checkformvalidation();">
 <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" onblur="checkvalue(this.value)">
 <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2">

  <button type="submit" id="butnid" >Go to page 1</button>
 <form>

<script>

function checkvalue(val)
{
 if(val==10)
  {
    document.getElementById("butnid").innerHTML = "Go to page 2";
  }

<script>
```

So my form goes to goes_to_page1.php and does some database operations. But I have called a function on onblur property of field1. So if the value of the field1 is 10, button's label changes to go to page 2. And if the value is 10, I want my page to redirect to goes_to_page2.php and do some other operation. Is it even possible to do so based on the text of a button?

```
goes_to_page1.php

<?php
$f1=$_POST['field1'];
$f2=$_POST['field2'];
// submit to table1 in database
?>

goes_to_page2.php
<?php

$f1=$_POST['field1'];
$f2=$_POST['field2'];
// do some other operation in database
?>
```

Comment: do not base it on client side. base it on the page where you have done some database operations

Comment: Can you be more specific?? @ejay_francisco

Comment: instead of calling a function `onblur` make your goes_to_page1.php check the value of your field1. then do your `if` `else` on that page to redirect if the value is 10

Answer (score 2):

this is the page1..

`$GLOBALS['f1']=$_POST['f1'];
$_GLOBALS['f2']=$_POST['f2'];
if($f1==10)
{`

`header("location:goes_to_page2.php");
exit;
}`

and in page 2

`$f1= $GLOBALS['f1'];
$f2=$GLOBALS['f2'];`

now the value of form is in the variable of page2..

is this the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the form action dynamically. Just like this-

```
if this
    document.<form-name>.action = "goes_to_page1.php";
else if that
    document.<form-name>.action = "goes_to_page2.php";
```

Comment: This code should be given inside a JavaScript function & call that function on onsubmit property of the form. Since, I am already calling another function for checking validation of the fields in the onsubmit property, is it even possible to implement this code??? Is it possible to call two functions in one property of a field??? @Sahil Mittal

Comment: You mentioned in the question that you have to check this on `checkvalue` function right? So simply write this snippet inside `checkvalue` function. Does this make sense?

Comment: checkval() is called before field2 is entered. So if I do as you say, I will redirect my form to another page before filing the form completely. @Sahil Mittal

Comment: ohk, so you just want to redirect to other page on `checkval()`?

Comment: I want to redirect to another page on button click based on the value from checkval() @Sahil Mittal

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($f1==10) { 
    header("location:goes_to_page2.php");
    exit;
}
```

did you mean this?

Comment: No..Not this. I want to submit an entire form with values in it to another page (goes_to_page2.php) if the value entered in textfield field1 is 10. I have to d some db operations in goes_to_page2.php & if value is not 10, then i have to perform some db operations in goes_to_page1.php. @red 2 mins ago
user3709308

Comment: then add global variable..im not sure in the syntax i think it is $_GLOBAL[''];

Comment: after that do the db operation in page2 and get the value of form using $f1= $_GLOBAL['variablename']; or use a $_SESSION['variablename']